# Google indexing pages very slowly

Tags: search-engine-indexing

Is there anything I can do to speed up the time it takes to index my pages? It's currently indexing them on it's own time I believe which is every 2 - 3 days and when working in music and media I need to have the latest post fairly quickly.

My *robots.txt* file is.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
sitemap: http://vipes.us/sitemapindex.xml
```

If I am understanding this correctly, I would put this URL into Google http://vipes.us/sitemapindex.xml.

But in doing so I still only get some of my pages indexed?

Comment: See my answer in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do, all things considered, is to post them in google+. You will also get bonus seo points.

Comment: How would I go about posting in google+? If you could provide me with a URL to read about this or even explain directly that would be amazing.

Comment: It depends on your content and strategy. From the little I saw you have a video blog, right? I would just create a page in g+ for the blog and post there daily the new blog posts **before** posting them elsewhere, eg fb. I would also mix some unique content there or some comments and engage with people. The main thing for your case is that google seems to index pages linked to through g+ faster. Same day. And if promoted correctly it can help you with your seo a lot too, since google tends to give a slight push to links in a specific "market" that are posted in g+ (or other google services).

Comment: I'd also suggest the posts you share through G+ are hashtagged.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools and add your site there. There you have an option for overriding Google Crawl rate from the default setting determined by Google.